# How to make the circumference of a Path/Bezier Curve Low Poly?

Tags: path, bezier-curves

I am working on a game asset and I wanted to create some wires, I'm relatively new to blender but I want to know how to make a low poly wire. The circumference is too round as it has too many vertices. I could not find a solution anywhere else.

It would be really helpful if one of y'all could give me a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select  your bevel object (curve circle). And in settings of this curve you should change the resolution value:

[image]

If you set it to `1` or `2`, I think, it will be close to that you want

Comment: Thank you so much. I messed around the bezier curve settings a lot but i forgot about the circle. m(_ _)m